# How to call all methods with certain naming pattern on object initialization

Tags: python, unit-testing

I started learning Selenium and I am curious how to realize behavior from the `PythonOrgSearch` class which inherits from `unittest.TestCase`. Namely, each method which starts with `test_` will be called automatically after initialization. I know this behavior is implemented in `TestCase` but I am interested in how to make something similar. Is there a design pattern that will take care of this?

And one bonus question, what is the point of `assert True`, since the condition is always `True`

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chorme\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://www.python.org")

    def test_example(self):
        print("Test")
        assert True

    def not_test(self):
        print("Not a test")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/unittest/loader.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with a metaclass which can customize the construction of your own classes. This a very powerful and general technique and arguably a Python design pattern.

Below is an example of it being applied to what you want to do. The metaclass' `__new__()` method looks through the contents of the class being defined—which is when it gets called—and looks for callable attributes whose names start with `test_`. After doing that, it defines `__init__()` and `post_init()` methods and makes them part of the class. The former calls the latter method which then iteratively calls all the methods defined that had matching names.

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
    """ Create class that calls an added post_init() method which in turn calls
        all method's whose names start with "test_".
    """
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classdict):

        # Get any class __init__() method defined.
        class_init = classdict.get('__init__', lambda *_, **__: None)

        test_funcs = [value for key, value in classdict.items()
                        if key.startswith('test_') and callable(value)]

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print('In metaclass generated __init__()')
            class_init(self, *args, **kwargs)  # Call class' __init__() method.
            self.post_init()

        def post_init(self):
            print('In metaclass generated post_init()')
            for method in test_funcs:
                print(f'calling {classname}.{method.__name__}()')
                method(self)

        classdict.update({'__init__': __init__,  # Attach methods to class.
                          'post_init': post_init})

        return type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, classdict)



class Example(metaclass=MyMetaClass):

    def __init__(self, arg, macnab=None):
        print(f'in Example.__init__({arg!r}, macnab={macnab!r})')

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_example1(self):
        print("Test1")

    def test_example2(self):
        print("Test2")

    def not_test(self):
        print("Not a test")

    def tearDown(self):
        print("Also not a test")
        pass


print('Creating instance of Example')
Example = Example(42, macnab='keyword')
```

Output:

```
Creating instance of Example
In metaclass generated __init__()
in Example.__init__(42, macnab='keyword')
In metaclass generated post_init()
calling Example.test_example1()
Test1
calling Example.test_example2()
Test2
```

Comment: Using this, basically I can "intercept" the class creation and add/redefine its behavior. Also in some way I can "limit" the way potential client uses it(class) if this was an API for example? Thank you for detailed answer and explanation

Comment: As I said, it's a very powerful technique. Not sure how you want to "limit" a client's use, but you can do things like wrap, decorate, or otherwise change the value of any methods or other attributes defined in the definition of the class that is a client of the metaclass (like `Example`). You can also remove them.

Comment: For example, you can intercept (before runtime) if some method is not defined in the derived class and raise TypeError. And I agree it is pretty powerful.

Comment: Indeed, all kinds of dynamic type-checking could also be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you can use `dir()` on `self` to get a list of its member ([Ufficial Documentation for dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#dir)).

After that, you can test the name pattern in some simple way, and if it is callable you can call it:

```
for name in dir(self):
    if name[:5] == 'test_' and callable(getattr(self, name)):
        res = getattr(self, name)()
        print(res)
```

Concerning you bonus question, it is a common practice to force the function to be overloaded.

Comment: Thank you, very useful answer, also I was not aware of this practice

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine they're simply finding callable methods that begin with "test_" using the `dir()` function. Something you could achieve pretty easily like:

```py
class CustomTestCaseRunner:
    def run(self):
        methods = [
            m for m in dir(self)
            if callable(getattr(self, m))
            and m.startswith("test_")
        ]

        for m in methods:
            print(f"Running {self.__class__.__name__}.{m}")
            getattr(self, m)()

class MyTest(CustomTestCaseRunner):
    def test_foo(self):
        assert True

    def test_bar(self):
        assert 1


MyTest().run()
# Running MyTest.test_bar
# Running MyTest.test_foo
```

As for your second question about `assert True`, it is unlikely you'd ever actually `assert True` in live code. That function appears to just be an example. `assert` is typically used on the response from a function. Here are a few examples:

```py
assert isinstance(1, int)
assert isinstance("foo", str)
```

When the condition evaluates to `False`, it will raise an `AssertionError` which will fail your test case.

Comment: This use of assertion makes sense, I like your way for the first part also. Thank you

Comment: I, too, like your technique — certainly easy to implement. I don't like the way you format list comprehension code, however…

Comment: To each their own (linter) :-)

Comment: Why using the list comprehension and then also a for loop? Is not less efficient?